# Is there a way to view passwords in plaintext?

Tags: password, find, text

I need to figure out a password, but I'm not supposed to change the password itself. Is there anyway, perhaps through the common-password file or a command to show the plaintext password of a user?

Comment: why would you do that ?

Comment: If you're talking about the login password, only its hash is stored in `/etc/shadow`. Good lucking matching a plaintext to that hash.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Any other input? Also, if you're familiar with xhydra, is there a file where used passwords would show?

Comment: You can try john ;) John the Ripper - see http://sectools.org/tool/john/

Comment: John the ripper would only work if the password is 3 or 4 letters long... unless you want to have it running for a couple of years.

Comment: @darent- That is completely wrong , I suggest you give john a try and see for yourself. John can not crack "strong" passwords, but length, alone, is not a strong password. John  will use dictionaries, which makes it much faster.